# Rails 3 application settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to keep application's settings editable by admin users through web form. I've found rails-settings gem to keep hash of simple string settings. But app settings need to keep not only string parameter but lists of another models (e.g. PaymentPeriods with name:string, etc).

My question is: how to organize such app settings in the  right way, so admin can have possibility to edit simple parameters and these lists.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some thinking i've got the idea that i can have a model Settings with N string parameters and there can be only one object of it. Plus add relations has_many to PaymentPeriods, etc. And finally this can be managed like simple nested form which is awesome described by Ryan Bates.

Will try it today. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try https://github.com/stephencelis/acts_as_singleton